# Symfony 4 - Entity nulled on database registration

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony4

I'm a Symfony beginner and been stuck on this issue for a while. I have two entities (Mairie and Ville) with a many-to-one relation. Ville is an imported table, pre-filled with info. In a form, the user creates an instance of Mairie and with the form data, it will find a Ville to bind to.

Problem is : doctrine does find a Ville object when the Mairie is created, but when I want to set it to the Mairie object, it is nulled. Here's my code, in the Controller :

```
    if($formMairie->isSubmitted() && $formMairie->isValid())
    {
        $repoMairie = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Mairie::class);
        $repoVilles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Villes::class);

        $inseeInput = $mairie->getInsee();

        $ville = $repoVilles->findOneBy(array("ville_code_commune" => $inseeInput));
        dump($ville);
```

This dump works : it finds the right instance of Ville in the database and returns an object filled with the right properties.

```
        $mairie->setVilles($ville);
```

This doesn't work, the Ville property of Mairie is set to null and I get no errors when I flush.

```
        $mairieVille = $mairie->getVilles();
        dump($mairieVille);
```

Returns null.

Why isn't the object registered ? I thought this could be an SQL issue since I've imported the Ville table but I can't find anything. I have used this method to bind other entities together and I've had no issue until now... Here are my two entities for more info (getters and setters not included) :

**Ville**:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Villes
*
* @ORM\Table(name="villes")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
 class Villes
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $ville_id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_departement", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_departement;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_slug;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_nom", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_nom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_nom_simple", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_nom_simple;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_nom_reel", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_nom_reel;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_nom_soundex", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_nom_soundex;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_nom_methaphone", type="string", length=22, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_nom_methaphone;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_code_postal", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_code_postal;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_commune", type="string", length=3, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_commune;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_code_commune", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
 */
private $ville_code_commune;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_arrondissement", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_arrondissement;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_canton", type="string", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_canton;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_amdi", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_amdi;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_population_2010", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_population_2010;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_population_1999", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_population_1999;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_population_2012", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_population_2012;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_densite_2010", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_densite_2010;

/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_surface", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_surface;

/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_longitude_deg", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_longitude_deg;

/**
 * @var float|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_latitude_deg", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_latitude_deg;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_longitude_grd", type="string", length=9, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_longitude_grd;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_latitude_grd", type="string", length=8, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_latitude_grd;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_longitude_dms", type="string", length=9, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_longitude_dms;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_latitude_dms", type="string", length=8, nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_latitude_dms;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_zmin", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_zmin;

/**
 * @var int|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville_zmax", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ville_zmax;
```

**Mairie**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Mairie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mairie", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="UNIQ_3946A254A73F0036", columns={"ville_id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_3946A254CF94313", columns={"office_tourisme_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mairie
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_nom_touristique", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieNomTouristique;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_descriptif_1", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieDescriptif1;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_descriptif_2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieDescriptif2;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_epci_rattachement", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieEpciRattachement;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_maire_nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieMaireNom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_maire_prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieMairePrenom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_adjoint_nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieAdjointNom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_adjoint_prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieAdjointPrenom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_contact_nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieContactNom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_contact_prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieContactPrenom;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_telephone_contact", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieTelephoneContact;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_email_contact", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieEmailContact;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_latitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieLatitude;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_longitude", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieLongitude;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_photo_1", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairiePhoto1;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_photo_2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairiePhoto2;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_photo_3", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairiePhoto3;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_photo_4", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairiePhoto4;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_taxe_sejour_gestionnaire", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieTaxeSejourGestionnaire;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_taxe_sejour_bareme", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieTaxeSejourBareme;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_sejour_lien", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieSejourLien;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_contact_nom_prenom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieContactNomPrenom;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_de_telephone", type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieDeTelephone;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_sejour_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieSejourEmail;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_rappel_texte", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieRappelTexte;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_rappel_lien", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieRappelLien;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_logo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieLogo;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_logo_2", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieLogo2;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_date_inscription", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieDateInscription;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_tampon", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieTampon;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_maire_signature", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieMaireSignature;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieSlug;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="insee", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $insee;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_adresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieAdresse;

/**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_complement_adresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $mairieComplementAdresse;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_postal_code", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairiePostalCode;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="mairie_commune", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $mairieCommune;

/**
 * @var \Villes
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Villes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ville_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var \OfficeTourisme
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OfficeTourisme")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="office_tourisme_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $officeTourisme;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->user_id_heb = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->hebergements = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->mairie_id_user = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->user = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->hebergement = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getVilles(): ?Villes
{
    return $this->ville;
}
public function setVilles(?Villes $villes): self
{
    $this->villes = $villes;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the getVilles() and setVilles() methods of your Mairie entity above?

Comment: Added at the end of the Mairie code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mairie :
The function setVilles

```
public function setVilles(?Villes $villes): self
{
    $this->villes = $villes;
    return $this;
}
```

Should'nt it be :

> $this->ville = $ville;

Because the property "Villes" with an S doesn't seem to exist.

So the function should be :

```
public function setVille(?Ville $ville): self
{
    $this->ville = $ville;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setVilles() function is seting $this->villes rather than $this->ville